# Cordova run browser not working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, cordova-cli

I have installed Cordova and built a basic app. The application is running fine in my android device. To make work easier, I was trying to run the Cordova browser platform. I ran the following commands in my project directory:

```
cordova platforms add browser
cordova run browser
```

The second command gives the following output:

```
Running command: /home/nitin/cordova_project/random_play/platforms/browser/cordova/run
```

but doesn't start any browser.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and have google chrome installed. I, also killed all the running instances of chrome by running

```
pkill chrome
```

before running the cordova command. Could someone please tell me how I can fix this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

1. Install google-chrome on ubuntu/linux
2. edit /platforms/browser/cordova/run
3. add additional case statement for linux before ending "}"
4. test with cordova run browser

Code:

```
case 'linux':
    spawn('google-chrome', ['--test-type', '--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir=/tmp/temp_chrome_user_data_dir_for_cordova_browser', project]);
    break;
```

Comment: You are amazing.. How did you get to this? you are a geek.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem running `cordova run browser`. It said there was no google-chrome. Apparently this option works `cordova run browser --target=firefox`. I guess you can use the browser you want. I am using cordova 5.3.3.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue in Debian, where Chromium is the Chrome-like browser.

Doing

```
ln -s /usr/bin/chromium /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

solved the problem.

**edit:** in Ubuntu distros chromium is under `/usr/bin/chromium-browser`

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 16.04, and the solution that **@habakuck** proposed worked for me. I do have a slight difference... I had to add "**-browser**" word to chromium:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/chromium-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Hope It helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem using the patch described here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7978. I'm quite disappointed that you still have to manually update files when the patch was released 6 months ago.

Another thing I had to do was using 'google-chrome' instead of 'chrome'. So instead of

```
var chromeProcess = spawn('chrome', args);
```

use

```
var chromeProcess = spawn('google-chrome', args);
```

Tried on cordova 4.3.0 and 5.0.0 and ubuntu 12.04.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install official Google Chrome browser - this should work out of the box